# How to enable forecast for a community user?

Tags: forecast, community

I want to make forecast tab visible in a community portal. How can I do that?

We have enabled salesforce communities in our environment which will be used by our employees to create lead, contacts, opportunities etc. They will not have a salesforce login instead they will be community portal users.

I have enabled forecasting for the users for whom we have created a salesforce account but I was wondering if there is a way to enable forecasting for the community users as well. I even tried checked "Allow forecasting" for individual community users but it didnt help.

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming the licenses you are using are community for external users ie customers. These do not permit forecasting functionality. Those who need to forecast are likely internal users and would require a full license.